# Elastic Search filtering in facets

Tags: search, elasticsearch, analytics

I want to simulate a parent child relation in elastic search and perform some analytics work over it. My use case is something like this

I have a shop owner like this

```
"_source": {
               "shopId": 5,
               "distributorId": 4,
               "stateId": 1,
               "partnerId": 2,
            }
```

and now have child records (for each day) like this:

```
"_source": {
                   "shopId": 5,
                   "date" : 2013-11-13,
                   "transactions": 150,
                   "amount": 1980,
                }
```

The parent is a record per store, while the child is the transactions each store does for 
day. Now I want to do some complex query like

Find out total transaction for each day for the last 30 days where distributor is 5

```
POST /newdb/shopsDaily/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "filter": {
      "has_parent": {
         "type": "shop",
         "query": {
            "match": {
               "distributorId": "5"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "facets": {
      "date": {
         "histogram": {
            "key_field": "date",
            "value_field": "transactions",
            "interval": 100
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But the result I get do not take the filtering into account which I applied.

So I changed the query to this:

```
POST /newdb/shopDaily/_search
{

      "query": {"filtered": {
         "query": {"match_all": {}},
         "filter": { "has_parent": {
            "type": "shop",
            "query": {"match": {
               "distributorId": "13"
            }}
         }}
      }}, 
      "facets": {
         "date": {
            "histogram": {
               "key_field": "date",
               "value_field": "transactions", 
               "interval": 100
            }
         }

      }
}
```

And then the final histogram facet took filtering into count.

So, when I browsed though I found out this is due to using `filtered`(which can only be used inside query clause and not outside like `filter`) rather than `filter`,
but it also mentioned that to have fast search you should use `filter`. Will searching as I did in second step (when I used `filtered` instead of `filter`) effect the performance of elastic search? If so, how can I make my facets honor filters and not effect the performance?

Thanks for you time

Comment: `filter` object in `filtered` query also performs faster search as it doesn't perform any scoring - this is similar to how the global `filter` works. See the last two lines over [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html)

Comment: @geeky_sh : That means there is no harm in using filter inside query since the result of filter irrespective of where it is used will be cached?

Comment: yeah, I think, that is what the documentation implies. I haven't tested it myself though.

Answer (score 0):

filters in Filtered query (filters in query clause) are cached, hence faster. These type of filters affect both search result and facet counts.
   Filters outside the query clause are not considered during facet calculations. They are considered only for search results. Facet is calculated only on the query clause. If you want filtered facets then you need to set filters to each of the facet clauses.